# How to enter data into an Internet Explorer website?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to enter info into an Internet Explorer 11 website form. The website/form was designed a long time ago (around 15-20 years). The website can only be accessed through Internet Explorer.

I cannot share the website/source code as it is internal to my company.

I have browsed online for a solution, but none worked (I tried many different versions).

I am looking to login, then go through a few pages of entering information, while clicking next/submit at each stage. I am failing after I login.

I have the following references on Excel:

Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft HTML Object Library, Microsoft XML, v6.0

I am following the wise owl tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShR33CdlY8. Skip to about 17 mins in to see where I got the code.

I got an error message at the line `htmlinput.Value = "excel"`.

The error message was

> object variable or with block variable not set - Run Time error '91'

```
Sub navigate_website()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlinput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate Sheet1.Range("C2").Text

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

'enter in userid
ie.document.forms("formsamplename").elements("usedid").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B6")
'enter in password
ie.document.forms("formsamplename").elements("userpassword").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B7")
'click the login button
ie.document.forms("formsamplename").elements("cmdSubmit").Click

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

' ----- I tried the below code as an alternative but it didn't work -----
'ie.document.forms("formsamplename").elements("usernumber").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B6")

Set htmldoc = ie.document
Set htmlinput = htmldoc.getElementById("usernumber")

htmlinput.Value = "excel" **'error occurs here**

' ----- I also tried the below code, but it didn't work -----
'htmldoc.forms("formsamplename").elements("usernumber").Value = "test"

Set ie = Nothing
Set htmldoc = Nothing
Set htmlinput = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What if you do `Dim htmlDoc as Object // Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application") // ... // Dim htmlPage as Object // Set htmlPage = htmlDoc.document // htmlPage.getElementById("usernumber").Value = "excel"`?

Comment: The second *Do While ie.Busy...* doesn't work because the browser status is already *complete*. Instead of that make a manual break for a few seconds to load the page after the click in the first part of code: **Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))**

Comment: @Zwenn, thanks for letting me know that the status is already complete when I had the second _do while loop_. I tried replacing the second _do while ie.busy_ with the _application wait_, but unfortunately it still does not work. I tried up to 15 seconds and I still get the error message at `htmlinput.Value = "excel"`

Comment: @BruchWayne, would you mind telling me exactly where to put in the changes/replacements/deletions? I tried some but none worked (I am new to VBA). Appreciate the response!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What happens when you do `Debug.Print htmlinput.ID` instead of `htmlinput.Value = "excel"`? If it prints `usernumber` in Immediate Window it means that the object is properly loaded at that stage of executing the code.

Comment: Alternatively, check if navigating directly to URL containing your username and password works, e.g. `http://user:password@example.com`. If yes, then you do not need to wait for a webpage to load for the second time.

Comment: @JustynaMK, I just tried that, but I got the same error message at 'Debug.Print htmlinput.ID'. Nothing appeared in the immediate window. I changed the second 'do while' to application wait as advised by Zwenn.

Comment: Thanks for checking - it looks like the webpage isn't loaded at that point. Did you try the second solution that I posted, i.e. using `http://user:password@example.com` as URL?

Comment: One more idea - try `Do // Set htmlinput = htmldoc.getElementById("usernumber") // Debug.Print htmlinput.ID // Loop Until Not htmlinput Is Nothing` and see if it works (watch out - might be an infinite loop; save your work before testing).

Comment: @JustynaMK, I am not entirely sure how to do that. I tried using a url of  `https://sampleurl/Default.aspx/usedid=sampleid&userpassword=samplepassword`

Comment: Are you sure there is an input element for text with the id *usernumber*? It would be very helpful if you post some html code.

Comment: No worries! If your webpage is `google.com`, username is `johnsmith`, and password is `pass123`, you can potentially use the following URL link without the need of authorizing the access - `http://johnsmith:pass123@google.com`. You don't even need to use VBA to test this solution, just paste the link into Internet Explorer and see if the webpage skipped the authorization steps.

Comment: @JustynaMK, thanks for your patience. When I do that I get a pop-up saying _Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer?_ I have a choice of _allow_ or _cancel_

Comment: Ah shame, I thought it would jump to the webpage straightaway. Do me a favor and try wrapping the loop code as follows: `On Error Resume Next` // `Do` // ... // `Loop Until Not htmlInput is Nothing` // `On Error GoTo 0` (note that you had `html` instead of `htmlInput` in your first try).

Comment: @Zwenn, this is what I can share, as it is an internal company website:
Please note I have changed the name and id (in my code I copied and pasted the real id)

`<INPUT name="usernumber" class="data" ... id="usernumber">`

Comment: @JustynaMK, good catch! I tried changing and it kept on running, I was able to login, but nothing happend after that. The macro did not complete. No error message displayed. My code is below:

On Error Resume Next
`Do
Set htmlinput = htmldoc.getElementById("usernumber")
Debug.Print htmlinput.ID
Loop Until Not htmlinput Is Nothing
On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: Sheesh. I'm slowly out of ideas... and I'm afraid if you don't find any solution, it will be time for you to start watching some more tutorials (i.e. `Selenium` VBA Library). Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your effort anyway, I wonder could their be restrictions that my company has put on the website... Will check out Selenium

Comment: You could also try IE.au3 in Autoit (www.autoitscript.com)

Comment: Fingers crossed! Also check: `1)` does it work if you first manually load the webpage and log in, and then trigger your VBA code (with `login` and `password` part removed) - I'm hoping that will remove the need for authentication; `2)` analyse what the webpage is doing after you input data into your boxes and press submit button (or whatever you want to do on this webpage). It might be that the webpage will be then re-directed to some other URL and all your inputs will become a part of the new URL... I'm out for now - good luck!

Comment: The error occurs when you attempted to use an object variable that isn't yet referencing a valid object. You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91) for the detail of the error. What about `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` before `ie.Visible = True`? Besides, you could add breakpoints before, on and after the error line to see if the code can execute line by line.